# Syntax error near Entity in a Package body

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl, vivado

I am trying to create a small package of gates and other components for a VHDL project. I have created my package and am instantiating a component from it in my test bench, but I am receiving this compiler error:

> ERROR: [VRFC 10-1412] syntax error near entity [/home/< redacted name >/Documents/school/ECE581/projects/project1/project_1/project_1.srcs/sources_1/new/components.vhdl:23]

**The Question**
What is the cause of my syntax error, and how do I resolve it?

**Package Code**

```
package p1_components is

    component cNAND
        port ( inA, inB : in bit;
               output   : out bit);
    end component;

end p1_components;

package body p1_components is

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- NAND implementation
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    entity cNAND is -- *** line 23 - error is reported here ***
        port ( inA, inB : in bit;
               output   : out bit);
    end cNAND;

    architecture def of cNAND is
    begin

        def_proc : process(inA, inB)
        begin

            if (inA and inB) then
                output <= transport '0' after 5 ns;
            else
                output <= transport '1' after 5 ns;
            end if;

        end def_proc;    
    end def;

end p1_components;
```

**Debugging Efforts**

I have been referencing some standard library code [here](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/src/std_logic_entities.vhd) and [here](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/src/std_logic_components.vhd) to ensure my declarations and syntax are correct, and as far as I can tell, they are. I have also referenced a couple of other online resources, and I can't find any issue with my package, component, and entity declarations.

**Other Notes**

1. I am compiling with the Linux version of Xilinx Vivado v2014.4 (64-bit).
2. I am aware of the VHDL keywords like `NAND`, which in a real-world design would make my implementations redundant. But the project I'm working on is for school, and there is a requirement that we roll our own NAND implementation for this portion of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I don't put an entity inside a package but outside. Try this:

```
package p1_components is

    component cNAND
        port ( inA, inB : in bit;
               output   : out bit);
    end component;

end p1_components;

package body p1_components is
end p1_components;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- NAND implementation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity cNAND is
    port ( inA, inB : in bit;
           output   : out bit);
end cNAND;

architecture def of cNAND is
begin

    def_proc : process(inA, inB)
    begin

        if (inA = '1' and inB = '1') then
            output <= transport '0' after 5 ns;
        else
            output <= transport '1' after 5 ns;

        end if;

    end process def_proc;
end def;
```

Comment: Yup. I just figured it out and was in the process of posting my own answer. Would you mind if I update your code to reflect my final working code? There are a couple of other errors I encountered once I resolved the one I asked about, and I'd like the answer here to be completely working.